# Grunt postman (newman) task hangs

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, postman

I'm running a grunt task that runs forever, with no output:

My `grunt.initConfig` includes

```
newman: {
        default_options: {
            options: {
                iterationCount: 1,
                collection: "tests/collection.postman_collection.json",
                environment: "tests/env.postman_collection.json"
            }
        }
```

Here's what I run from the terminal. The newman grunt task runs indefinitely.

```
Running "newman:default_options" (newman) task
^C

Execution Time (2016-10-07 16:38:54 UTC-5)
loading tasks              1s  
newman:default_options  16.2s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman collections can be exported as `v1` and `v2`, and the Grunt task plugin only works with collections of type `v1`